# mac java encoding for german umlaut characters

Tags: java, macos, encoding, swt

I have created an test swt application which has some German special characters. When I run this application from eclipse it works fine but if I create jar of application and run jar from terminal it shows wrong special characters.

For example I have shown "**Sie sind sicher, dass Sie, um die Aufnahme zu schließen?**" message on closing the application but when I run application from terminal it shows characters as shown in image.

[image]

As you can see in image there are some special characters which are not displayed correctly.

I am using Mac Lion. JDK details are

java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3646)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)

I am running application from terminal using following command

java -cp :./final/* mypackege.MainClass -d32 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

I tried specifying UTF encoding from commandline but no effect.

Comment: Where does the string come from? Is it in your code directly?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, I have hard coded the string in program.

Comment: Okay, in that case my answer is *probably* right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us how you're getting the string, but if it's in the source code, it's probably just a matter of specifying the encoding when you build, e.g.

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 ...
```

Obviously tailor this to whatever encoding your source code is *actually* in.